# Echo exact string from .bat file to another .bat file

Tags: batch-file, echo

please be gentle...

I am trying to create a .bat script to create another .bat script using variables set in the first script.
All of my other 'echo's' have outputted in the correct format to SS_Update.bat. But I am struggling with a few lines that fail to copy across correctly. In "Setup New SS.bat" I have... (out of context)

```
echo for /r %Tempfolder% %%%a in (*.zip) do set sszip=%%%~nxa >> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\%Site%\SS_Update.bat
echo for /r %Tempfolder% %%%a in (*.zip) do set tempfile=%%%~dpnxa >> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\%Site%\SS_Update.bat
echo for /f %%%i in (%currentss%) do set date1=%%%~ti >> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\%Site%\SS_Update.bat
echo for /f %%%i in (%extractedss%) do set date2=%%%~ti >> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\%Site%\SS_Update.bat
echo for /f %%%i in ('DIR /B /O:D %currentss% %extractedss%') do echo Current SS is older than the Extracted SS or missing... >> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\%Site%\SS_Update.bat
```

The results in "SS_Update.bat" are...

```
for /r C:\Users\Pelican\Documents\Temp %%~nxa
for /r C:\Users\Pelican\Documents\Temp %%~dpnxa
for /f %currentss%~ti
for /f %extractedss%~ti
for /f %D  ') do echo Current SS is older than the Extracted SS or missing...
```

I understand that I need to escape some special characters i.e I wanted %% so I used %%%. I have tried all the combinations I can think of using examples from [Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) but I keep getting far from what I am after.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are missing an extra `%` in your `set`, like `set sszip=%%%%~nxa`

Answer (score 0):

You can ease the task by prepending the lines with a var which includes the echo and redirection, so the code looks normal aside from necessary doubling % and escaping `<>|&`.

```
Set _=^>^> "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\%Site%\SS_Update.bat" Echo
%_% for /r %Tempfolder% %%%%a in (*.zip) do set sszip=%%%%~nxa 
%_% for /r %Tempfolder% %%%%a in (*.zip) do set tempfile=%%%%~dpnxa
%_% for /f %%%%i in (%currentss%) do set date1=%%%%~ti
%_% for /f %%%%i in (%extractedss%) do set date2=%%%%~ti
%_% for /f %%%%i in ('DIR /B /O:D %currentss% %extractedss%') do echo Current SS is older than the Extracted SS or missing...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to enclose the commands within a single redirect. *(the only issue is in escaping the internal closing parentheses using the standard circumflex character)*. To escape a single percent character you use another percent character, so for two to be echoed you'll need four.

```bat
>>"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\%Site%\SS_Update.bat" (
    ECHO FOR /R "%Tempfolder%" %%%%A IN (*.zip^) DO SET "sszip=%%%%~nxA"
    ECHO FOR /R "%Tempfolder%" %%%%A IN (*.zip^) DO SET "tempfile=%%%%~dpnxA"
    ECHO FOR /F %%%%I IN (%currentss%^) DO SET "date1=%%%%~tI"
    ECHO FOR /F %%%%I IN (%extractedss%^) DO SET "date2=%%%%~tI"
    ECHO FOR /F %%%%I IN ('DIR/B/OD %currentss% %extractedss%'^) DO (
    ECHO    ECHO Current SS is older than the Extracted SS or missing...^)
)
```